# Show random urls from string list in Androidstudio

Tags: android, string, url, random, onclicklistener

I want, when u press my button video, he randomly takes a url from my string list and goes to the url. How i can do this, i really dont know.

```
public class Easy extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);

    final String[] vList = {"https://www.google.com",
            "https://www.youtube.com"};
        findViewById(R.id.video).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(vList));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace

```
i.setData(Uri.parse(vList));
```

with

```
Random random = new Random();
i.setData(Uri.parse(vList[random.nextInt(vList.length)]));
```

and make sure to put

```
import java.util.Random;
```

in your import statements.